# Query All Rows Within a Table based on Id's in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table that includes 53 rows, in my database. The variables in the rows are INT id, VARCHAR var, and INT votes. I can't figure out how to query all the rows within the table into an array. I want to be able to get the 'var' variable while referencing the id. Here is what I have so far, which indeed will only query the first row. (hence id = '1').

```
<?php

include_once "code.php";
$new_array = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Variables WHERE id='1'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
};
```

I tried using a for loop and sticking a variable where the '1' is, but that's not working either. If you could please also show me how to get the var variable from referencing any of the ids that be great. Thanks

Comment: How PhpMyAdmin is connected with your PHP code?

Comment: you don't query phpmyadmin. that's a management interface. you query the mysql database... and if you want all the records in the table, then don't have a `where` clause in the first place. SQL is one of the few things in life where the less you specify, the more you get.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Like so: <?php
 $username = "xyz";
 $password = "xyx";
 $host = "localhost";
 $name = "xyz";
 
 @mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die ("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
 @mysql_select_db("$name") or die ("No database under name");

?>

Comment: It's not about PhpMyAdmin at all.

Comment: @MarcB Could you show me a example of how to reference the var's based on ID's once I get query without the `WHERE`?

Comment: YOu keep re-initializing your `new_array` inside the loop, so effectively you'll only ever get the LAST record.

Comment: @MarcB I put the `new_array` outside of the loop. How do i grab all the rows and put them into the array, while still being able to reference the array by the 'id' to get the 'var'?

Comment: exactly as you are. you just needed to stop destroying previously done work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `$new_array` for each row. You should move it outside the `while` loop. Also, try not to use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. Try mysqli_* or even better PDO.

```
include_once "code.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Variables");
$new_array = array(); //This array should be not inside while
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
    //Do something else here if you want
};
```

Using PDO

```
try {
    $link= new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
    echo "PDO connection object created";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
//Prepare your query
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
//Execute your query binding variables
$result = $stmt->execute(array());
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$new_array = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Edit after the comment:

Remove the `WHERE id = '1'` from you query and you will have all your rows. Then you can take the var referenced by id using:

```
echo $new_array[1]['var'];
echo $new_array[2]['var'];
```

Comment: That's still not working for me. It's only grabbing the 1st one. Sense id is specified to '1'.

Comment: If you specify id as 1 then you will take only one row.

Comment: Right, what I'm wanting to do is take all 53 rows and put it into an array. Then be able to reference the id to get the var.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to remove the WHERE id = '1' from your query and you will have all your rows. Then you can take the var referenced by id using: echo $new_array[1]['var]; echo $new_array[2]['var];